# Plotting longitudinal data

Tags: r, data-visualization, count-data

I have a dataset consisting of Olympic Games medals tally, population Size and GDP of 140 countries for 10 years. How do I plot this data set to show the change in medal tally with change in population and GDP over the years?
I am working on a project where I am trying to find a relationship between the no of medals a country wins and its gdp and population in that year. My theory is that countries with higher GDP can afford better infrastructure for their athletes and hence have better results in olympics.

Comment: Welcome kris91. You can do this many different ways. Can you amplify your question to indicate more specifically what story you are trying to tell?

Comment: Do you need to display the raw data, or just the predicted effects? Do you have a model already, or is this preliminary / exploratory visualization? If you have a model, does it have an interaction b/t the 2 explanatory variables? It sounds like your primary hypothesis centers on GDP, are you comfortable stratifying on population for your plots? How interested are you in visualizing individual trajectories vs the mean trend?

Comment: This is a preliminary visualization.